# Selecting across multiple tables with UNION

Tags: mysql, select, union

I reworked my database from one user table to multiple user tables (divided per role): `tblStudents`, `tblTeachers`, `tblAdmin`

When logging in, I didn't want to run three queries to check if the user exists somewhere in my DB. So what I did was put together the following query with `union`

```
select s.id as id, s.email as email, s.password as password, s.role as role from tblStudents s
union
select a.id as id, a.email as email, a.password as password, a.role as role from tblAdmin a
union
select t.id as id, t.email as email, t.password as password, t.role as role from tblTeachers t
```

This selects the fields that are the same across all tables and outputs the results nicely for me.

So, I decided to try this and for some reason, my login form wouldn't work. For my login form, I added a `where` clause which checks for the email address. I ran the query in my database app and surprisingly, when I do for example `where email = "admin@admin.be"` (this email exists in my database `tblAdmin`), it also selects a record from my students table.

With the where clause:

```
select s.id as id, s.email as email, s.password as password, s.role as role from tblStudents s
union
select a.id as id, a.email as email, a.password as password, a.role as role from tblAdmin a
union
select t.id as id, t.email as email, t.password as password, t.role as role from tblTeachers t
where email = "admin@admin.be"
```

The records both `have id = 1` but I don't understand why it would select the student record when I'm filtering on the admin email address. Why is this? Can someone explain and provide me with a better solution to this problem? I basically have one login form and need to select across multiple tables to check if the user exists in my db.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be your full query, as there is no filtering in it.  Can you post the whole query?

Comment: Thought that would be clear; updated with the other query :)

Comment: I notice you're not putting the string in quotes.  Is that a mistype?

Comment: If you mean the email = one, ya, I forgot it there; edited.

Comment: On a related topic; try to avoid using "" to quote your strings.  MySQL does unfortunately allow this, but if you ever have to migrate to another DB it'll spit the dummy at you.  Using '' instead is the SQL standard and will work on MySQL *and* everything else.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for updating the query; now we can see that the WHERE condition is only applied to the *last* UNIONed query.  You need to *either* add that WHERE clause to each query, or wrap it as a subselect and apply the WHERE clause to that.

```
select s.id as id, s.email as email, s.password as password, s.role as role from tblStudents s
where email = "admin@admin.be"
union
select a.id as id, a.email as email, a.password as password, a.role as role from tblAdmin a
where email = "admin@admin.be"
union
select t.id as id, t.email as email, t.password as password, t.role as role from tblTeachers t
where email = "admin@admin.be"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (
select s.id as id, s.email as email, s.password as password, s.role as role from tblStudents s
union
select a.id as id, a.email as email, a.password as password, a.role as role from tblAdmin a
union
select t.id as id, t.email as email, t.password as password, t.role as role from tblTeachers t
) foo where email = "admin@admin.be"
```

Comment: With the second example, I get the following error: 'Every derived table must have its own alias'.

Comment: What does that 'foo' do exactly? Is it the same as what I do with `tblAdmin a`? Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's an alias for the subselect; it just gives it a name that you can refer to, like when you do "select s.id as id".  This would allow you to select only certain fields from the subselect by saying `select foo.email FROM (...) foo`.  If it makes it more clear, you can (in most RDBMSs) say "AS foo" instead of just "foo".  The name itself is arbitrary; call it whatever you like, I just use foo by default :)

Comment: Okay, makes sense now. I called it 'users' for clearness' sake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the query return what you wanted after the change?

Comment: You better use first approach, because union need to retrieve all the data from the 3 tables ... order them ... then remove duplicates so when ever you can limit the number of rows before combining the results... its better!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    R.co_C,
    company3.Statuss
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            company1.co_C
        FROM
            company1
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                company2.co_C
            FROM
                company2
    ) AS R
LEFT JOIN company3 ON R.co_C = company3.co_A;
```