# Mysql - select from multiple tables without producing duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have three tables and I would like to select from the tables without producing duplicates.

The table are as follows:

**Customers**

```
id     |     name   |     lastName  
---------------------------------------
1      |    john    |      doe
2      |    helen   |      keller
```

**Orders**

The userID column is a foreign key that references John Doe, so John orders 3 items.

```
id     |   userID   |     order 
---------------------------------------
1      |    1       |      pizza
2      |    1       |      pasta
3      |    1       |      lasagna
```

**CustomerRating**

The userID column is a foreign key that references John Doe, so John leaves 5 reviews.

```
 id     |   userID  |     rating   |  comment
-------------------------------------------------
1      |    1       |      5/5     |  was good
2      |    1       |      5/5     |  excellent
3      |    1       |      4/5     |  great
4      |    1       |      4/5     |  great
5      |    1       |      4/5     |  great
```

How would I select from the 3 tables where I can get a return results that look like this?

```
id     |     name   |     lastName    |   order      |   rating
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      |    john    |      doe        |   pasta      |   5/5
       |            |                 |   pizza      |   5/5
       |            |                 |   lasagna    |   4/5
       |            |                 |              |   4/5
       |            |                 |              |   4/5
```

I've tried joining these tables, but since John has left 5 reviews and only ordered 3 times, the id, name,lastName, and order columns gets filled with duplicate data.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting across multiple tables with UNION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066197/selecting-across-multiple-tables-with-union)

Comment: Post the result you want

Comment: @worldofjr Union queries need to have the same number of columns, so that wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: @bad_boy the results have already been posted..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience in MySQL but I assume that it works similar to MSSQL.

So the format in which you are expecting the output is not possible. You can rather get the order and rating column values as comma separated

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492563/2782985) is a similar kind of question that might help you

including example based on link
try something like this

`SELECT Customers.id, Customers.name, Customers.lastName, 
GROUP_CONCAT(Orders.order) OrderedDishes,
GROUP_CONCAT(CustomerRating.rating) RatingsGiven
FROM 
..... rest of your query .....`

Comment: @MisterDood i agree, will try to correct it

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to discard duplicates (`SELECT DISTINCT`, `UNION`, `GROUP BY`) but it is not clear whether users update existing rating or create new ones. And what you want to see: the last rating or the average one

On the other note - i would change your entire setup:

- `order` table would contain `order_id`, `customer_id`and other order related stuff like `order_date`
- `products` table that would describe each of your dishes and their info like price, description etc
- `order_products` table with fields `order_id` and `prduct_id`
- if users rate products then your rating table would need at least `product_id`, `customer_id`, `rate_value`. I'd also add `ratingDate` That way you can get averages or select the last one by `Max(ratingDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an orderID field to the CustomerRating table else there is no way to relate an item to its rating.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to relate an item to its rating.