# How to get join multiple queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa0e17/4 as you can see id is primary key and auto incremented and values column is int type. To retrieve count based on value I am doing 4 different queries

```
select count(id) from status where value=1
select count(id )from status where value=2
select count(id) from status where value=3
select count(id) from status where value=4
```

My requirement is to get all those counts in a single query.

Why I want?

The above table is just a demo table and have only 4 queries but in my scenario I have 35 queries and so I have to do 35 methods in java.

Expected output: 4,,4,4,4 (1st query result, 2nd query result, 3rd query result, 4th query result)

Comment: Please post expected output format.

Comment: @wewesthemenace Please check now

Comment: So, you're expecting a single row output?

Comment: @wewesthemenace yes.It does not matter to be done only in sql,If you know how to use storedprocedure for this scenario then also please answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 2 normal ways of solving it:

Example 1 PIVOT:

```
SELECT [1] count1,[2] count2,[3] count3,[4] count4
FROM  
( 
  SELECT id, value 
  FROM status
) p 
PIVOT (COUNT(id) FOR [value] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS pvt
```

Use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONCAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) if you want to combine the columns into one.

To do this, replace first row in first example with:

```
SELECT CONCAT([1],',',[2],',',[3],',',[4])
```

Example 2 CASE:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 1 END) count1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 2 THEN 1 END) count2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 3 THEN 1 END) count3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 4 THEN 1 END) count4
FROM status
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select value, count(id)
from status 
group by value
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have to have use where condition in my case.In the fiddle I provided only one parameter(id) but in my case there are 2 or 3 paramaters(but in all id parametrer is commmon)

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` (or `UNION ALL` to preserve duplicate values) like:

```
select count(id) from status where value=1
UNION
select count(id )from status where value=2
UNION
select count(id) from status where value=3
UNION
select count(id) from status where value=4
```

Have a look at a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066234

**[Edit 1]**

Check the fiddle, it works on my machine ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b89ef/1/0

Since I removed a (3) from the insert, you get 4,3 (I'm only selecting fours and threes here).

**[Edit 2]**

I did not catch the part where you wanted it all on one line.

Just wrap a `SELECT` around your statements like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa0e17/34/0:

```
select
  (select count(id) from status where value=1),
  (select count(id) from status where value=2),
  (select count(id) from status where value=3),
  (select count(id) from status where value=4)
;
```

And your result is one row with 4,4,4,4 as result.

Comment: union discards non-distinct values so using his example you would only get one result row with one column.

Comment: Then use Union All to preserve duplicates.

Comment: your answer is useful so +1

Answer (score 1):

You should better count rows and group by the value by the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM status GROUP BY value
```

or for a better description and look try this:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM status GROUP BY value
```

Comment: This is ok if I need to compare with only one column(id) ,how to if I have to compare with other columns also

Comment: just add them both to select (if necessary) and group by (must!!!) clause. For fıurther details on use of GROUP BY clause please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: I hope using this schema : create table status(
  id int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),value int, category int );

insert into status values(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 2),(4, 2),(1, 3),(2, 2),(3, 1),(4, 1),(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 2),(4, 2),(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 2),(4, 2)

Comment: with this query: provides more help: SELECT value, category, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM status GROUP BY value, category

Comment: This is just a dummy table and all dummy values.So I am just comparing with one parameter

Comment: Then group by with only that spesific parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a comma-delimited string, then this might be helpful:

```
WITH CTE(N) AS(
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM STATUS WHERE VALUE=1 UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(ID )FROM STATUS WHERE VALUE=2 UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM STATUS WHERE VALUE=3 UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM STATUS WHERE VALUE=4 UNION ALL
)
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT N', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), N) 
    FROM CTE FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
, 1 , 2 , N'')
```